# Mariadb wont start

Tags: mariadb

Mariadb does not start, no matter what I do. 
It always looks like:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.23-9+deb9u1) ...
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-05 15:44:03 CEST; 9ms ago
  Process: 9713 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9623 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9619 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9616 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9713 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jul 05 15:43:59 v22015121382329682 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Jul 05 15:44:00 v22015121382329682 mysqld[9713]: 2017-07-05 15:44:00 140711653892672 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1) starting as process 9713 ...
Jul 05 15:44:03 v22015121382329682 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 05 15:44:03 v22015121382329682 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Jul 05 15:44:03 v22015121382329682 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 05 15:44:03 v22015121382329682 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-mysql-server:
 default-mysql-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1; however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on default-mysql-server; however:
  Package default-mysql-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 default-mysql-server
 mysql-server
```

I already uninstalled and reinstalled all mariadb packages, but it does not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please copy and paste the terminal output instead! Was mysql installed previously?

Comment: Yes mysql was installed

Comment: Did you completely remove it, I mean purge it?

Comment: Yes I followed this instruction: https://askubuntu.com/a/708822/672607